# R: Weighted Joyplot/Ridgeplot/Density Plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gplots, ggridges, ridgeline-plot

I am trying to create a joyplot using the `ggridges` package (based on `ggplot2`). The general idea is that a joyplot creates nicely scaled stacked density plots. However, I cannot seem to produce one of these using weighted density. Is there some way of incorporating sampling weights (for weighted density) in the calculation of the densities in the creation of a joyplot?

Here's a link to the documentation for the `ggridges` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/ggridges.pdf I know a lot of packages based on ggplot can accept additional aesthetics, but I don't know how to add weights to this type of geom object.

Additionally, here is an example of an unweighted joyplot in ggplot. I am trying to convert this to a weighted plot with the density weighted according to pweight.

```
# Load package, set seed
library(ggplot)
set.seed(1)

# Create an example dataset
dat <- data.frame(group = c(rep("A",100), rep("B",100)),
                  pweight = runif(200),
                  val = runif(200))

# Create an example of an unweighted joyplot
ggplot(dat, aes(x = val, y = group)) + geom_density_ridges(scale= 0.95)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data.

Comment: Added a reproducible example, per @MrFlick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the way to do this is to use [`stat_density`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density.html) rather than the default `stat_density_ridges`. Per the docs you linked to:

> Note that the default `stat_density_ridges` makes joint density
>   estimation across all datasets. This may not generate the desired
>   result when using faceted plots. As an alternative, you can set
>   `stat = "density"` to use `stat_density`. In this case, it is required
>   to add the aesthetic mapping `height = ..density..` (see examples).

Fortunately, `stat_density` (unlike `stat_density_ridges`) understands the aesthetic `weight` and will pass it to the underlying `density` call. You end up with something like:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = val, y = group)) +
  geom_density_ridges(aes(height=..density..,  # Notice the additional
                          weight=pweight),     # aes mappings
                      scale= 0.95,
                      stat="density") # and use of stat_density
```

The `..density..` variable is automatically generated by `stat_density`.

**Note:** It appears that when you use `stat_density` the x-axis range behaves a little differently: it will trim the density plot to the data range and drop the nice-looking tails. You can easily correct this by manually expanding your x-axis, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: This is quite helpful, thank you! Are you able to show how this works in an example?

Comment: I get `Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: weight` for this option.

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out? I'm getting the `Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: weight` as well.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it spits out the warning, but the weighting is actually working. Mapping the weight aesthetic definitely changes the resulting graph.